# GitHub Undo a (not most recent) Merge

Tags: git, github, rebase

I have a master branch that looks like this:

```
A-B- C -D-E-F
   \   /
    H-I
```

Where H and I are commits to the same branch made by another developer, and D is the commit from merging I and C.  I want to remove all code from the commits H and I.  I essentially want the branch to look like:

```
A-B-C-E-F
```

My plan was to do:

```
git rebase --onto C E
git push origin master --force
```

No other developers have branches or forks or anything that this would upset.  Will these commands do what I want?  I don't need the -p flag on the rebase do I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
git rebase -i C
```

In the rebase a document will come up for you to edit, you delete the lines for the commits you want to remove (H and I).  Then I had to fix a bunch of merge conflicts, and eventually call:

```
git push origin master --force
```

I was about 9 commits past the ones I wanted to remove and I had to merge 5 or 6 times, some times the same changes in the same file for whatever reason.  This might not be a good answer if you are 100 commits down the line.